# How to use darts BlockRNNModel/N-BEATS for multivariate dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recurrent-neural-network, forecast

I have a dataframe with pm2.5, pm1 and pm10 data, recorded every 3 hours. In total I have 3687 records. I want to split the data into test-train for 20%-80% and then implement the multivariate BlockRNNModel/N-BEATS from the darts library. How can I predict the pm2.5 values using the other two sensors, and also the historic pm2.5 values? So far I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from darts.timeseries import TimeSeries
from darts.dataprocessing.transformers import Scaler
from darts.models import BlockRNNModel
from darts.metrics import mape, smape
from darts.dataprocessing.transformers import Scaler
from darts.utils.timeseries_generation import datetime_attribute_timeseries
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("air_quality_final.csv", infer_datetime_format=True)
df.index = df['TimeStamp']

df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'])
df=df[['pm25','pm1','pm10']]

df=TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df)
scaler_df = Scaler()
series_df_scaled = scaler_df.fit_transform(df)

train_df, val_df = series_df_scaled[df[:-int(20/100*len(df))]], series_df_scaled[df[-int(20/100*len(df)):]]
```

And here is how the data looks like:

```
TimeSeries (DataArray) TimeStamp: 3687 component: 3 sample: 1
array([[[10.        ],
        [ 3.        ],
        [ 3.        ]],

       [[ 9.4       ],
        [ 2.86666667],
        [ 2.86666667]],

       [[ 8.8       ],
        [ 2.73333333],
        [ 2.73333333]],

       ...,

       [[15.        ],
        [12.        ],
        [17.        ]],

       [[20.84615385],
        [12.8974359 ],
        [22.58536585]],

       [[ 7.36363636],
        [ 3.86363636],
        [ 7.17391304]]])
Coordinates:
TimeStamp
(TimeStamp)
datetime64[ns]
2021-01-09T15:00:00 ... 2022-04-...
component
(component)
object
'pm25' 'pm1' 'pm10'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

An example from the [Darts documentation](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/userguide/forecasting_overview.html#support-for-multivariate-series) shows that you need to **stack** the series to create multivariate series data structure. In your case you need to stack *pm2.5* and the *other two variables* that you want to use.

Following is an example of Multivariate prediction using KalmanForecaster (should also be applicable to other multivariate forecasting model such as BlockRNNModel/N-BEATS as you asked):

```
import darts.utils.timeseries_generation as tg
from darts.models import KalmanForecaster
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

series1 = tg.sine_timeseries(value_frequency=0.05, length=100) + 0.1 * tg.gaussian_timeseries(length=100)
series2 = tg.sine_timeseries(value_frequency=0.02, length=100) + 0.2 * tg.gaussian_timeseries(length=100)

multivariate_series = series1.stack(series2)

model = KalmanForecaster(dim_x=4)
model.fit(multivariate_series)
pred = model.predict(n=50, num_samples=100)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
multivariate_series.plot(lw=3)
pred.plot(lw=3, label='forecast')
```